# Bus isolation circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, i2c, bus, smbus

I got a question about BUS isolation circuits.
[image]

Is this a correct design?
Looks not to me.
The book said that if POWOK is high, two SMBUS will connect together.
But I think it's wrong, the NMOS should be turned on when POWOK is low.....

The other circuits is like shown below.
I think its purpose is to isolate two power plane of the BUS.
When no power, the MOS is off to prevent the current from the outside ( to the SOC), and when power on and R/W data, if the data is high, the MOS will be off, and the other side will be pulled-up to the level as its power. and when data is low, it can pass through the NMOS to the other side.
Please correct if anything wrong here.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first schematic if the POWOK is low it will turn off the NPN transistor allowing the collector resistor to pull the two FET gates to the positive voltage and thus allow the SMBus isolator to function between the VCC3 and the 3VSB power domains.

The second schematic is used to allow SMBus level conversion for the IPMB interface between the 3V3SB domain and the 5VSB domain. No particular power gating is intended by this circuit. It is just that typical off board interface for IPMB has been 5V signalling levels since legacy times and most modern on-board controllers (SOC, chipset or BMC) will be using 3.3V signalling for SMBus.

Comment: Thanks Michael for the feedback! So am I right about how it works in 2nd schematics? That is, if left side signal is high, NMOS will be turned off, and the right side will be pulled-up by 5V, and complete the level shifting, and vis versa. And if one side is low, it'll pass through the NMOS and make the other side also low, since the NMOS is ON now. :)

Comment: Yes you are correct. But when the 5V side pulls low the initial behavior is that the body diode of the NFET conducts first starting to pull down the source side of the on the 3.3V side. This starts to turn the FET on and then the low on the first side gets connected through to the low on the second side.

Comment: Great explanation!! Excellent! :)